# Vuejs set v-model on input change

Tags: vue.js

I want to have `v-model` and `value` set in one input. Here is my code:

```html
<td>
    <input v-model="invoice.items[n-1].net_price" type="number" step="0.01" min="1" form="invoice-form">
</td>
<td v-if="invoice.items[n-1].net_price && invoice.items[n-1].quantity">
    <input :value="(invoice.items[n-1].net_price * invoice.items[n-1].quantity).toFixed(2)" type="text" form="invoice-form" readonly>
</td>
<td v-else>
    <input type="text" readonly>
</td>
```

Problem is with 2nd input. Now it works like this:

1. You input value in `net-price` input
2. You input quantity
3. It calculates a value and set it in `readonly` input

Now I want to set `v-model` in this 2nd input, but when I try to do this I get an error.
Is there a way to set a model to this calculated value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more robust approach is to perhaps put your calculation logic in a method and use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to unpack the values off the individual items. In addition, the variables can also be assigned [default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values) in the case that the unpacked values are `undefined` -- That way, you no longer need to worry about the computed values returning `NaN` since they will fallback to zeros when they are.

Try something like that:

```js
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    invoice: {
      items: [
        {
          net_price: 30.05,
          quantity: 4
        },
        {
          net_price: 14.99,
          quantity: 7
        },
      ]
    }
  }),

  methods: {
    calculate({ net_price = 0, quantity = 0}) {
      return (net_price * quantity).toFixed(2);
    }
  }
})
.$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form id="invoice-form">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Net Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(item, index) of invoice.items" :key="index">
          <td>
            <input v-model="item.net_price" type="number" step="0.01" min="1" form="invoice-form" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input v-model="item.quantity" type="number" min="0" form="invoice-form" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input :value="calculate(item)" form="invoice-form" readonly />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```